# Integral problems containing DiracDelta functions.

Tags: definite-integrals, dirac-delta, multiple-integral

$\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\delta (6 c+5 \text{R2}) \delta (30 a+24 \text{R1}-5 \text{R2}) \exp \left(-\frac{24 \text{R1}^2-48 \text{R1} \text{S1}+25 \text{R2}^2-50 \text{R2} \text{S2}+24 \text{S1}^2+25 \text{S2}^2}{30 b^2}\right)d\text{R2}d\text{R1}$

How to calculate this integral? This integral cannot be calculated in Mathematica (MMA).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the integral can be rearranged as

$$I=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(6 c+5 R_2) \left(\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(30 a+24 R_1-5 R_2) \exp\left(-\frac{24 R_1^2-48 R_1 S_1+25 R_2^2-50 R_2 S_2+24 S_1^2+25 S_2^2}{30 b^2}\right) \, dR_1\right) \, dR_2$$

which can then be evaluated using the [composition with a function property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Composition_with_a_function) of $\delta(g(x))$.

---

Mathematica actually gives the result

$$I=\frac{1}{120} \exp \left(-\frac{75 a^2+30 a (c+4 S_1)+75 c^2+24 c (S_1+5 S_2)+48 S_1^2+50 S_2^2}{60 b^2}\right)$$

for this integral assuming $a\in\mathbb{R}\land c\in\mathbb{R}$ which agrees with evaluation using the composition property.

Comment: Dividing into two integrals can yield results. Thank you for your help.